# Firestore GeoQuery using GeoFire - Node.js - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to **firebase functions** and **Node.js JavaScript**. I have written code as per firebase documentation. I am trying to **geo-query firestore collection** using **geofire** with Node.js JavaScript. But I am seeing an error

> geofire is not defined

Here is my code. What should i do to solve this error?

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.sortQuery = functions.firestore.document('query_sorted/{user_uid}').onWrite(async (change, context) => {
    const user_uid = context.params.user_uid;
    var docAfter = change.after;
    var nearby_array = [];
    var max_distance = '';
    var latitude = '';
    var longitude = '';
    var geohash = '';

    nearby_array = docAfter.get('nearby');
    console.log('NEARBY ARRAY SIZE .'+nearby_array.length);

    const usersRef = admin.firestore().collection('users');
    const updateRef = admin.firestore().collection('query_sorted').doc(user_uid);
    const user_doc = admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(user_uid);

    if(user_doc.exists){
        max_distance = user_doc.get('max_distance');
        latitude = user_doc.get('latitude');
        longitude = user_doc.get('longitude');
        geohash = user_doc.get('geohash');
    }


    if(nearby_array.length < 50) {

        console.log('NEARBY IF STATEMENT REACHED .'+global_array.length);
        const center = [26.3492374, 89.6293433];
        const radiusInM = 50 * 1000;
        
        const bounds = geofire.geohashQueryBounds(center, radiusInM);
        const promises = [];
        for (const b of bounds) {
            const q = usersRef
            .orderBy('geohash')
            .startAt(b[0])
            .endAt(b[1]);
            
            promises.push(q.get());
        }
        
        // Collect all the query results together into a single list
        
        Promise.all(promises).then(async (snapshots) => {
            const matchingDocs = [];
            
            for (const snap of snapshots) {
                for (const doc of snap.docs) {
                    const lat = doc.get('latitude');
                    const lng = doc.get('longitude');
                    const uid = doc.get('uid');
                    
                    // We have to filter out a few false positives due to GeoHash
                    // accuracy, but most will match
                    
                    const distanceInKm = geofire.distanceBetween([lat, lng], center);
                    const distanceInM = distanceInKm * 1000;
                    if (distanceInM <= radiusInM) {
                        await updateRef.update({nearby: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion('sorting_inside_successfull_'+uid)});
                        matchingDocs.push(doc);
                    }
                }
            }
            
            return matchingDocs;
        
        }).then((matchingDocs) => {
            // Process the matching documents
            // ...
        
        });    
    }
    
    return null;
});
```

I also tried after mentioning `const geofire = require('geofire-common');` before `admin.initializeApp();` . See the below code:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const geofire = require('geofire');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
```

That did not work. This time I see an error while trying to deploy functions:

> Function failed on loading user code. This is likely due to a bug in the user code.

Comment: "I also tried after mentioning const geofire = require('geofire-common'); before admin.initializeApp(); . That did not work. I see error while trying to deploy functions" Please update your question to show exactly what you did, and the exact error you get during deploy.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen please check updated question